# History exam question

Tags: discussion, questions

Should [this question about remembering things form  exams](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/4465/103), with a soft focus on history be on topic?

I think it is not because the core of the question is *how to remember things for exams* and has little to do with history: an expert on passing exams without knowledge of history would be better suited to answer this question than an expert in history without any knowledge of exams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, its not in the scope of the FAQ and similar to the References question that was recently closed.  We can help with specifics on historical topics but doing better in a course should be handled with the teacher and people should be able to find their own study methods in college so they can apply them to other courses.